# TSQL XQUERY Question - Not sure if it's my XQUERY syntax or poorly formed XML thats the issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm not sure if it's my XQUERY code here or that the XML column's data is poorly formed.

```
-- drop table #tmp

create table #tmp ([id] varchar(20), [type]     varchar(100), [name] varchar(100), [item] XML)
go

insert into #tmp ([id], [type], [name], [item])
values
('1', 'APP', 'type1', '<appdata            source="applicationdata" name="name1" value="FlowRate"     units="people/h" />')
    go
insert into #tmp ([id], [type], [name], [item])
values
('2', 'APP', 'type2', '<appdata source="applicationdata" name="name2" value="FlowRate" units="people/h" />')
go
insert into #tmp ([id], [type], [name], [item])
values
('3', 'APP', 'type3', '<appdata source="applicationdata" name="name3" value="FlowRate" units="people/h" />')
go

-- select * from #tmp 

-- attempt 1
select tt.[id], tt.[type], tt.[name],
C.value('source','varchar(100)') as [source],
C.value('name','varchar(100)') as [name],
C.value('value','varchar(100)') as [value],
C.value('units','varchar(100)') as [units]
from #tmp tt
cross apply 
item.nodes('/appdata') as T(C)

-- atempt 1 result
-- singleton error

-- attempt 2
select tt.[id], tt.[type], tt.[name],

C.query('source').value('.', 'varchar(1000)') as     [source],
C.query('name').value('.', 'varchar(1000)') as [name],
C.query('value').value('.', 'varchar(1000)') as [value],
C.query('units').value('.', 'varchar(1000)') as     [units]

from #tmp tt
cross apply 
item.nodes('/.') as T(C)
outer apply C.nodes ('appdata') as S(D)

-- attempt 2 result
-- xml column values don't shred
```

The contents of the XML column doesn't have an element escape tag and the contents all seem to be added in as attributes. Is XQUERY able to process "XML" formed like this or do i need to manipulate it?

FYI, I was able to return data using a single XML string and the sp_xml_preparedocument SP, but i  really want to shred these attributes out into separate columns of the same table.

Comment: Uh, you're querying attributes of the node, so you want "@source", "@name" etc... Your first query should work just by adjusting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tt.[id], tt.[type], tt.[name],
C.value('@source','varchar(100)') as [source],
C.value('@name','varchar(100)') as [name],
C.value('@value','varchar(100)') as [value],
C.value('@units','varchar(100)') as [units]
from #tmp tt
cross apply 
item.nodes('/appdata') as T(C)
```

Comment: Correct answer, +1 from my side

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd been tinkering around with this format but hadn't added the @ sign before the attribute.

Comment: For anyone reading this post in the future, you don't need to put the @ sign in front if you are naming the element (contained in < and /> tags), only if you are searching for attributes of an element (e.g. source="Ipsum")

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgalla/2005/12/15/transforming-xml-data-into-a-rowset-using-the-nodes-method/

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one `<appdata>` element per row, you can omit `.nodes()` and call this like here:

```
select tt.[id], tt.[type], tt.[name],
tt.item.value('(/appdata/@source)[1]','varchar(100)') as [source],
tt.item.value('(/appdata/@name)[1]','varchar(100)') as [name],
tt.item.value('(/appdata/@value)[1]','varchar(100)') as [value],
tt.item.value('(/appdata/@units)[1]','varchar(100)') as [units]
from #tmp tt;
```

This would be slightly faster...

If performance doesn't matter, go with deep patel's answer, which is a little easier to read IMO...

Comment: Thanks for your response Shrugo, I'll keep this in mind if performance wanes